# Return to first frame after video finished playing

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

Im in a big trouble, can any one help me please..?

My problem is I want to return my flashplayer into first frame after playing the external video.

The following script is used for my flash player,

```
function checkTime(flv)
{
    var _loc2 = flv.playheadTime;
    var _loc3 = Math.floor(_loc2 / 60);
    var _loc1 = Math.floor(_loc2 % 60);
    if (_loc1 < 10)
    {

        _loc1 = "0" + _loc1;
    } // end if

    current_time.text = _loc3 + ":" + _loc1;
} // End of the function
flv.pauseButton = pause_btn;
flv.playButton = play_btn;
flv.FLVPlayback.align = center;
var time_interval = setInterval(checkTime, 500, flv);

ffwd_btn.onRelease = function ()
{
    flv.seek(flv.playheadTime + 2);
};
rewind_btn.onRelease = function ()
{
    flv.seek(flv.playheadTime - 5);
};
mute_btn.onRelease = function ()
{
    if (videoSound.getVolume() == 0)
    {
        videoSound.start();
        videoSound.setVolume(volLevel);
    }
    else
    {
        volLevel = _root.videoSound.getVolume();
        videoSound.setVolume(0);
        videoSound.stop();
    } // end else if
};
var videoSound = new Sound(this);
videoSound.setVolume(100);
flv.contentPath = flvurl;
fl.video.FLVPlayback.align = center;
```

If anyone knows please modify the script and give reply,
I'm looking forward to your replies..

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var listenerObject:Object = new Object();
listenerObject.complete = function(eventObject:Object):Void {
        gotoAndPlay(0);
};
flv.addEventListener("complete", listenerObject);
```

Comment: FindZen thanks a lot, it works huh!!!!! But still there is one problem "NaNa" is showing the timeline after the video finish, is there any way to show its 00:00 ..?